# error while loading shared libraries: libkeybinder-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, flutter, shared-libraries, manifest, flatpak

I'm trying to package a Flutter application for flatpak & created a configuration file too. Everything gets built fine & no errors are shown while building/installing locally
But when I try to run the app with flatpak this error is shown

```sh
/app/spotube/spotube: error while loading shared libraries: libkeybinder-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here's my flatpak manifest file:

```yaml
app-id: oss.krtirtho.Spotube
runtime: org.gnome.Platform
runtime-version: '40'
sdk: org.gnome.Sdk
command: spotube
finish-args:
  - --socket=x11
  - --socket=fallback-x11 
  - --socket=wayland
  - --socket=pulseaudio
  - --share=network
  - --device=dri
  - --filesystem=~/.local/share
modules:
  - name: spotube
    buildsystem: simple
    build-commands:
      - install -dm755 /app/share/applications /app/share/icons/spotube /app/bin /app/spotube
      - cp -R spotube/ /app
      - cp spotube/spotube.desktop /app/share/applications
      - cp spotube/spotube-logo.png /app/share/icons/spotube
      - ln -s /app/spotube/spotube /app/bin/spotube
    sources:
      - type: archive
        only_arches:
          - x86_64
        url: https://github.com/KRTirtho/spotube/releases/download/v1.0.1/Spotube-linux-x86_64.tar.xz
        dest: spotube
        sha256: 117f379c4e32a03cf1a596345e14ba82d9c143cc0ff5ac49a6e10fdc7a3d5178
```

This was the output while building the package with the command `flatpak-builder build/flatpak oss.krtirtho.Spotube.yml`

```sh
Downloading sources
Starting build of oss.krtirtho.Spotube
Cache miss, checking out last cache hit
========================================================================
Building module spotube in /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/build/spotube-1
========================================================================
Running: install -dm755 /app/share/applications /app/share/icons/spotube /app/bin /app/spotube
Running: cp -R spotube/ /app
Running: cp spotube/spotube.desktop /app/share/applications
Running: cp spotube/spotube-logo.png /app/share/icons/spotube
Running: ln -s /app/spotube/spotube /app/bin/spotube
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/spotube
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/spotube
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/spotube to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/spotube.debug
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libhotkey_manager_plugin.so
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libhotkey_manager_plugin.so
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libhotkey_manager_plugin.so to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/lib/libhotkey_manager_plugin.so.debug
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liburl_launcher_linux_plugin.so
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liburl_launcher_linux_plugin.so
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liburl_launcher_linux_plugin.so to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/lib/liburl_launcher_linux_plugin.so.debug
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libwinmedia.so
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libwinmedia.so
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libwinmedia.so to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/lib/libwinmedia.so.debug
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liblibwinmedia_plugin.so
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liblibwinmedia_plugin.so
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/liblibwinmedia_plugin.so to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/lib/liblibwinmedia_plugin.so.debug
compressing debuginfo in: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libbitsdojo_window_linux_plugin.so
processing: /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libbitsdojo_window_linux_plugin.so
Nothing to do.
stripping /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/spotube/lib/libbitsdojo_window_linux_plugin.so to /home/krtirtho/dev/spotube/.flatpak-builder/rofiles/rofiles-Cu6rD8/files/lib/debug/spotube/lib/libbitsdojo_window_linux_plugin.so.debug
Committing stage build-spotube to cache
Cleaning up
Committing stage cleanup to cache
Finishing app
Not exporting share/applications/spotube.desktop, non-allowed export filename
Not exporting share/icons/spotube/spotube-logo.png, non-allowed export filename
Please review the exported files and the metadata
Committing stage finish to cache
Pruning cache
```

This is the log while installing the package locally with the command `flatpak-builder --user --install --force-clean build/flatpak oss.krtirtho.Spotube.yml`

```sh
Emptying app dir 'build/flatpak'
Downloading sources
Starting build of oss.krtirtho.Spotube
Cache hit for spotube, skipping build
Cache hit for cleanup, skipping
Cache hit for finish, skipping
Everything cached, checking out from cache
Exporting oss.krtirtho.Spotube to repo
Commit: 288604714b36bce991ad7f4e7576e99d1aee3adb3484a1c17fa70fdd8e9821cb
Metadata Total: 41
Metadata Written: 3
Content Total: 26
Content Written: 0
Content Bytes Written: 0 (0 bytes)
Exporting oss.krtirtho.Spotube.Debug to repo
Commit: 32c8f080cfdf44910c3d27bee1db491125eaef91a9d8a1c5713961655f1fc00e
Metadata Total: 11
Metadata Written: 1
Content Total: 7
Content Written: 0
Content Bytes Written: 0 (0 bytes)
Installing app/oss.krtirtho.Spotube/x86_64/master
Pruning cache
```

The structure of the archive `Spotube-linux-x86_64.tar.xz` file

```sh
spotube.tar.xz
├── data
│   ├── flutter_assets
│   │   ├── AssetManifest.json
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   ├── spotube_banner.png
│   │   │   ├── spotube-logo.png
│   │   │   ├── spotube-logo.svg
│   │   │   └── spotube-screenshot.png
│   │   ├── FontManifest.json
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   │   └── MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
│   │   ├── NOTICES.Z
│   │   ├── packages
│   │   │   └── cupertino_icons
│   │   │       └── assets
│   │   │           └── CupertinoIcons.ttf
│   │   └── version.json
│   └── icudtl.dat
├── lib
│   ├── libapp.so
│   ├── libbitsdojo_window_linux_plugin.so
│   ├── libflutter_linux_gtk.so
│   ├── libhotkey_manager_plugin.so
│   ├── liblibwinmedia_plugin.so
│   ├── liburl_launcher_linux_plugin.so
│   └── libwinmedia.so
├── spotube
├── spotube-logo.png
└── spotube.desktop
```

Github Link: https://github.com/KRTirtho/spotube

Comment: I didn't read all your text, this is about the missing `libkeybinder-3.0.so.0` only :  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libkeybinder-3.0.so.0 .... i.e. if Debian / Ubuntu, please install `libkeybinder-3.0-0` ..... and if Fedora / RHEL / CentOS it's `keybinder3`

Comment: I do have `libkeybinder-3.0-0` installed. But for some reason flatpak's throwing error about this